# rust error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body

Tags: rust, closures, rust-polars

The following code tries to asynchronously update a master dataframe `df` (from polars package) after getting a `msg` by concatenating it.

I have seen the "duplicate" posts on stack overflow but still don't understand what I am doing wrong. I just want to mutably borrow the dataframe and update it, that's all! I tried it with a string, and it worked fine...

```rust
pub async fn new_handler(endpoint: &str) -> tokio::task::JoinHandle<()> {
    // Make master df for this handler
    let mut df = DataFrame::empty().lazy();
    // Make a stream for this handler
    let stream = new_stream(endpoint).await;
    let handle = tokio::spawn(async move {
        // let handle = tokio::spawn(async {
        stream
            .for_each(|msg| async move {
                match msg {
                    Ok(msg) => {
                        // Parse the json message into a struct
                        let jsonmsg: AggTrade =
                            serde_json::from_str(&msg.to_string()).expect("Failed to parse json");
                        let s0 = Series::new(
                            "price",
                            vec![jsonmsg.price.parse::<f32>().expect("Failed to parse price")],
                        );
                        let s1 = Series::new(
                            "quantity",
                            vec![jsonmsg
                                .quantity
                                .parse::<f32>()
                                .expect("Failed to parse quantity")],
                        );
                        // Create new dataframe from the json data
                        let df2 = DataFrame::new(vec![s0.clone(), s1.clone()]).unwrap().lazy();
                        // append the new data from df2 to the master df
                        df = polars::prelude::concat([df, df2], false, true)
                            .expect("Failed to concat");
                    }
                    Err(e) => {
                        println!("Error: {}", e);
                    }
                }
            })
            .await
    });
    handle
}
```

I get the following error:

```
error: captured variable cannot escape `FnMut` closure body
  --> src/websockets.rs:33:29
   |
27 |       let mut df = DataFrame::empty().lazy();
   |           ------ variable defined here
...
33 |               .for_each(|msg| async {
   |  ___________________________-_^
   | |                           |
   | |                           inferred to be a `FnMut` closure
34 | |                 match msg {
35 | |                     Ok(msg) => {
36 | |                         // Parse the json message into a struct
...  |
58 | |                         df = polars::prelude::concat([df.clone(), df2.clone()], false, true)
   | |                                                       -- variable captured here
...  |
86 | |                 }
87 | |             })
   | |_____________^ returns an `async` block that contains a reference to a captured variable, which then escapes the closure body
   |
   = note: `FnMut` closures only have access to their captured variables while they are executing...
   = note: ...therefore, they cannot allow references to captured variables to escape
```

Comment: I think the solution might be to create the clone of `msg` outside the `async` block: `|msg| {let msg = msg.to_string(); async move {...}}`.

Comment: @cafce25 sorry, i do not know where i should clone that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem is that the closure passed to `stream.for_each()` can be called multiple times, but the `df` variable is moved into the closure when it's referenced by the `df.clone()` call.

Here's a self-contained minimal code example showing the same compilation error. If you uncomment the last lines in the function, it will fail to compile:

```rust
async fn fails_moved_into_closure_called_multiple_times() {
    println!("fails_moved_into_closure_called_multiple_times():");
    let mut df = vec![];

    let closure = || async move {
        let new_value = df.len();
        println!("in the closure, pushing {}", new_value);
        df.push(new_value);
    };

    let future = closure();
    future.await;

    let future2 = closure();  // FAIL
    future2.await;

    println!("final value: {:?}", df);  // FAIL
}
```

In fact, Rust can't be sure that your `for_each` function doesn't call the closure multiple time concurrently in multiple threads. Here's a solution using `Arc<Mutex<T>>` that is thread-safe and fixes the ownership issues:

```rust
async fn fix_using_arc() {
    println!("fix_using_arc():");
    let df = Arc::new(Mutex::new(vec![]));

    let closure = || async {
        let my_df = Arc::clone(&df);
        let mut shared = my_df.lock().unwrap();
        let new_value = shared.len();
        println!("in the closure, pushing {}", new_value);
        shared.push(new_value);
    };

    let future = closure();
    future.await;

    let future2 = closure();
    future2.await;

    println!("final value: {:?}", df);
}
```